# network performance tunning in Linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have a application which has two threads ,thread1 would receive multicast packages
from network card eth1 , suppose I use sched_setaffinity to set cpu affinity
for thread1 to cpu core 1 , and then I have thread2 to use these packages
(received from thread1,located in heap area global vars) to do some operations ,
I set cpu affinity for thread2 to core 7 ,suppose core 1 and core 7 are 
in the same core with hyper-threading , I think the performance would be good, 
since core 1 and core 7 can use L1 cache .

I have watched /proc/interrupt , I see eth1 has interrupts in several cpu cores ,
so in my case , I set cpu affinity to core 1 for thread1 ,but interrupts happened
in many cores , would it effect performance ? those packages received from eth1 
would go directly to main memory no matter which core has the interrupt ?

I don't know much about network in linux kernel , may anyone who would suggest
books or websites can help me for this topic ? Thanks for any comments ~~

Edit : according to "What every programmer should know about memory" 6.3.5 "Direct Cache Access" , I think "DCA" is hwat i like to know ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt will (quite likely) happen on a different core than the one receiving the packet. Depending on how the driver deals with packets, that may or may not matter. If the driver reads the packet (e.g. to makle a copy), then it's not ideal, as the cache gets filled on a different CPU. But if the packet is just loaded into memory somewhere using DMA, and left there for the software to pick up later, then it doesn't matter [in fact, it's better to have it happen on a different CPU, as "your" cpu gets more time to do other things].

As to using hyperthreading, my experience (and that of many others) is that hyperthreading SOMETIMES gives a benefit, but often ends up being similar to not having hyperthreading, because the two threads use the same execution units of the same core. You may want to compare the throughput with both threads set to affinity on the same core as well, to see if that makes it "better" or "worse" - like most things, it's often details that make a difference, so your code may be slightly different from someone elses, meaning it works better in one or the other of the cases.

Edit: if your system has multiple sockets, you may also want to ensure that the CPU on the socket "nearest" (as in the number of QPI/PCI bridge hops) the network card.

Comment: Thank you ,Mats , my server only have one cpu socket, 6 cores with hyper-threading , make it 12 units , may I ask , how can I make sure the net card use DMA or not ? if those packets would use DMA, then since all packets would go directly to main memory first  , in this case ,those packets load into main moery and will goes to my thread1 running core(core 1) cache, am I correct ?

Comment: You don't KNOW (without looking at the source code of the driver) exactly how it works. But most cards will just write directly to memory without involving the CPU. This means the only "cache-activity" you will see is the invalidation of the cachelines as the data comes in that overwrite data that is already in the cache. 

The main memory is not "per core", so whichever core your thread is running on will fill its cache with the relevant data as the packet is being processed.